# Explicit C major key signature in lilypond

Tags: lilypond, key-signatures

I am typesetting some exercises in lilypond, and would like to make the "all natural" key signature when the exercises are in C more explicit.

I would like to set the key as c major and see every note, in the signature not the music, marked explicitly with a natural sign.

Can anyone help with a way to do so.

Thanks in advance for your help and for time.
T.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
\new Staff
{
  \set Staff.keyAlterations = #'((3 . 0) (0 . 0) (4 . 0)
                                 (1 . 0) (5 . 0) (2 . 0) (6 . 0))
  c' e' g' c'
}
```

Of course this kind of visual is rubbish since the positions of the natural signs are that of *sharps* rather than flats even though there is no reason to assume either at the start of the system.

So the logic for these visuals is broken, even though you can convince LilyPond to produce them (you can produce the visuals for flat cancellation by starting with `((6 . 0) (2 . 0) (5 . 0)` ... namely the same list backwards).

Comment: Great. Thankyou. Just a note for anyone else that maybe looking at this, it only works (at time of writing) with the development release 2.19.65, not the latest stable 2.18.2. That confused for a moment, but it works well. As for it being a less than ideal indicator given an unnatural (pardon the pun) order needing to be chosen, I take your point. I will have to think on that. For now though this works well enough for my purposes. Thankyou.